# GnuPlot : feed each column from different files

Tags: matlab, gnuplot

I would like to plot a 3D graph fed from two different data files.
The first one would have the Z-data, stored in the following way, where the columns have different sizes:

```
X00 Z00     X10     Z10     X20     Z20... XN0 ZN0
X01 Z01     X11     Z11     X21     Z21
X02 Z02     X12     Z12     X22     Z23
....
X0A Z0A     X1A     Z1A     X2A     Z2A     ...
            X1(A+1) Z1(A+1) X2(A+1) Z2(A+1) ...
...

            X1B     Z1B     X2B     Z2B
            X1(B+1) Z1(B+1) X2(B+1) Z2(B+1) ...
...    
            X1C     Z1C    
            X1(C+1) Z1(C+1)
```

The second file would contain the Y data, in the appropriate format:

```
Y00 Y10 Y20
...
```

I would need the equivalent to the following matlab code (where I already have separately read the columns, and then formed the appropriate XZ matrix data). Note that 'data' matrix, is a matrix of dimensions(2N x C) where C is the max size of the largest column. The remaining non-exiting data (for shorter columns) is filled with 'Nan' value.
Is there a way to use pm3d to achieve that?

```
        yData=[1,2,3,5,7,10];
        figure;
        hold all;
        for yIndex=1:length(yData)
            col = yIndex*2;
            colSize=length(data(:,col));
            plot3(yData(yIndex)*ones(colSize),data(:,col-1),data(:,col));
        end
        xlabel('x');
        ylabel('y');
        zlabel('z');
        grid on;
        hold off;
```

Comment: You cannot do  this directly in gnuplot. Use any external script to prepare your data in an appropriate format for gnuplot.